# Aplicacion de android en unity basado en OpenCV nativo

Tags: android, c#, c++, unity3d, opencv

tengo una pequeña duda que espero que podáis solucionármelo.

quiero crear una aplicación de android en unity. La aplicación consiste en activar la cámara del dispositivo y verla en pantalla. Para ello me quiero basar en un código nativo c++ basado en OpenCV.

tengo el código generado, pero al ejecutar la aplicación, se ve la escena pero no la imagen, y tengo la sensación que es porque la función VideoCapture de OpenCV no la estoy utilizando bien para android. podéis ayudarme? os adjunto el código:

C++

```
__declspec(dllexport) void iniciar(int& widt, int& heigh) {
camera.open(0);
if (!camera.isOpened())
{
    return;
}
widt = (int)camera.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
heigh = (int)camera.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
trueRect.x = 5;
trueRect.y = 5;
trueRect.width = 100;
trueRect.height = 100;
midX = 1;
midY = 1;
wi = 0;
he = 0;
}


__declspec(dllexport)
void video(unsigned char* arr) {
Mat frame;
Mat resi;
Mat dst;//dst image
camera >> frame;
if (frame.empty()) {
    return;
}
flip(frame, dst,1);
//resize(dst, resi, Size(width, height));
cv::cvtColor(dst, dst, COLOR_BGR2RGB);
copy(dst.datastart, dst.dataend, arr);
}
```

C#:

```
public class camara : MonoBehaviour {

[DllImport("NativoPrincipio")]
public static extern void video(byte[] img);

[DllImport("NativoPrincipio")]
public static extern void iniciar(ref int widt, ref int heigh);

WebCamTexture back;
Texture2D textura;
byte[] imgData;
int width = 0;
int height = 0;


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    back = new WebCamTexture();
    //GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = back;
    //back.Play();
    iniciar(ref width, ref height);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
{
    imgData = new byte[width * height * 4];
    video(imgData);
    textura = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
    textura.LoadRawTextureData(imgData);
    textura.Apply();
    GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = textura;
    imgData = null;
    textura = null;

}}
```

Comment: Yo la verdad es que no he usado esas tecnologías, pero aqui [tienes un ejemplo](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/35284), tal vez analizarlo pueda ayudarte :)

Comment: No me sirve, dado que no puedo acceder al código nativo.

Comment: Ok, como en el ejemplo ponia que era compatible con android pensé que podria servirte. Lo siento, a ver si alguien pude ayudarte